# How to assign variable to data frame based on year? Dplyr: case_when issues

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, variable-assignment

My issue relates to myself not being able to assign a discount_rate (variable) to my data frame based on year.

I have a data frame of customers details, and then the discount rates for each type (M, R & O) by year where 1=2019 and 2=2020 etc. Sample data as so:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  customer_type = c('M', 'R', 'O', 'M', 'M'),
                  year = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3))
```

Now I have discount rates for the 5 years 2019 to 2023, example:

```
discount_rates <- data.frame(year = c(2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023),
                  metro_M = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.1),
                  regional_R = c(0.01, 0.1, 0.02, 0.11, 0.09),
                  overseas_O = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5))
```

What I want to do is add on to df1 the discount rates for the relevant year.

Example output as so:
| ID |customer_type|year|discount_rate|
|----|-------------|----|-------------|
| 1  | M           |1   |0.1          |
| 2  | R           |1   |0.01         |
| 3  | O           |2   |0.3          |
| 4  | M           |2   |0.2          |
| 5  | M           |3   |0.3          |

what I have tried is using a case_when statement:

```
df1$discount_rate <-
  case_when(
    df1$customer_type == "M" ~ metro_M[[df1$year]],
    df1$customer_type == "O" ~ overseas_O[[df1$year]],
    df1$customer_type == "R" ~ regional_R[[df1$year]],
    TRUE ~ 0
  )
```

but that way I get error: *"attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex"*

I am stumped on this, and would greatly appreciate if others knew a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your `discount_rates` df to long format and use a `left_join` to assign the discount rates like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

discount_rates_long <- discount_rates %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year, values_to = "discount_rate") %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("label", "customer_type"))

df1 %>% 
  mutate(year = 2018 + year) %>% 
  left_join(discount_rates_long, by = c("year", "customer_type"))
#>   ID customer_type year    label discount_rate
#> 1  1             M 2019    metro          0.10
#> 2  2             R 2019 regional          0.01
#> 3  3             O 2020 overseas          0.30
#> 4  4             M 2020    metro          0.20
#> 5  5             M 2021    metro          0.30
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan, I initially was hesitant to use a left join as I thought that might take a while (500k rows) but this was surprisingly quick!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  customer_type = c('M', 'R', 'O', 'M', 'M'),
                  year = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3))

discount_rates <- data.frame(year = c(2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023),
                             metro_M = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.1),
                             regional_R = c(0.01, 0.1, 0.02, 0.11, 0.09),
                             overseas_O = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5))


df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(year=2018+year)

df2 <- left_join(df1,discount_rates,by="year")

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(discount_rate = case_when(
    customer_type == "M" ~ metro_M,
    customer_type == "O" ~ overseas_O,
    customer_type == "R" ~ regional_R,
    TRUE ~ 0))
```

Result :

```
  ID customer_type year metro_M regional_R overseas_O discount_rate
1  1             M 2019     0.1       0.01        0.2          0.10
2  2             R 2019     0.1       0.01        0.2          0.01
3  3             O 2020     0.2       0.10        0.3          0.30
4  4             M 2020     0.2       0.10        0.3          0.20
5  5             M 2021     0.3       0.02        0.4          0.30
```